# My table has an extra cell

Tags: javascript

I have a table and there is a extra blank cell that appears on top of the table. You enter a name and the name inserts into the table and there's a counter on top that counts how many names there are. Could someone look at my code and tell me how to fix it.

```
var userNames = [];


function getName() {
    //Variables
    var input;
    var userName;
    //Initializes input
    input = document.getElementById("nameInput");
    //Reads input
    userName = input.value;
    //Assigns userName
    userNames[userNames.length] = userName;
    //Clears the input
    input.value = "";
    input.focus();
}


function printTotal() {
    //Constants
    var LABEL = "Total: ";
    //Variables
    var total;
    var output;
    //Initializes output
    output = document.getElementById("totalOutput");
    //Gets number
    total = userNames.length;
    //Output
    output.innerHTML = LABEL + total;
}


function printNames() {
    //Constants
    var OPEN_CELL = "<tr style=\"height : 1.5eM;\"><td>";
    var CLOSE_CELL = "</tr></td>";
    var ONE = 1;
    //Varialbles
    var output;
    var index;

    output = document.getElementById("nameOutput");

    index = userNames.length - ONE;

    output.innerHTML += OPEN_CELL + userNames[index] + CLOSE_CELL;
}

function project62Part2() {
    // Your code goes in here.
    getName();
    printTotal();
    printNames();
    return false;
}
```

HTML file code

```
<div id="outputDiv" class="output">
<form action="#" onsubmit="return project62Part2();">
    <label for="nameInput" style="float : left;">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameInput" style="float : left;" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" style="float : left; clear : left" />
    <!--<p id="totalOutput">
    </p>-->
    <table id="nameOutput">
        <tr>
            <th id="totalOutput">
                Total: 0
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">project62Part2();</script>
```

Comment: Does fixing the `CLOSE_CELL` definition work? It should be `"</td></tr>"`.

Comment: I just tried that and no change.

Comment: Do you really need  `<script type="text/javascript">project62Part2();</script>`? I think the initial call to `getName()` creates an empty entry in the `userNames` array

Answer (score 1):

You run Project62Part2() at page-load. Your use of userNames[userNames.length] is actually correct, because you're adding a new item at the tail of a 0-based array. However, your initial execution of getName, while the input is empty, is inserting an empty string into userNames[0].

I suggest some basic validation:

```
if (userName != "") 
userNames[userNames.length] = userName;
```

You probably don't want to insert blanks anyway, yes?

Answer (score 1):

As Paul commented, the answer is that the initial call to `project62Part2()` runs that function, which calls `getName()`, which gets an empty value for the input, and adds that to the array.

You only need to call the function on form submit.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZKqD/) for proof.

Comment: So remove the function project62Part2()?

Comment: No, don't remove the function itself. Just remove the call to it in your code at the end of the HTML: `<script type="text/javascript">project62Part2();</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Markup of CLOSE_CELL is not correct. You should have the end tag of cell first, followed by end tag of the row.

```
var OPEN_CELL = "<tr style=\"height : 1.5eM;\"><td>";
var CLOSE_CELL = "</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the extraneous call to `project62Part2()`, I recommend considering DOM manipulation rather than straight strings and playing with `innerHTML`. For example:

```
function printNames() {
  var output = document.getElementById("nameOutput");

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.style.height = '1.5em';
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var content = document.createTextNode(userNames[userNames.length - 1]);

  td.appendChild(content);
  tr.appendChild(td);
  output.tBodies[0].appendChild(tr);
}
```